# On some finiteness properties for schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dimension-theory

Consider the following properties of scheme $X$:

A: $X$ is of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$

B: $X$ is Noetherian

C: $X$ is of finite Krull dimension

What implications are there between these three? I believe that B and C are independent of each other (although I can't find a reference right now), and it follows from EGA I, 6.3.7 that A implies B. But does A imply C?

(Apologies if this question is "trivial", but I'm not an expert in algebraic geometry.)

As an aside, I would also be interested if any of these properties can be related to some notion of cohomological dimension (not sure what kind of topologies would be relevant for this).

Comment: C.f. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21067/noetherian-rings-of-infinite-krull-dimension

Comment: (By the way, your question -- which is more of a commutative algebra question than an algebraic geometry question -- is a standard one.  It is certainly not trivial: indeed, the first example of a Noetherian ring of infinite Krull dimension is due to Nagata, and is one of the most famous examples in the entire subject.)

Comment: Dear Anon, Grothendieck's vanishing theorem says that the cohomology of a sheaf on an $n$-dimensional Noetherian space vanishes in dimensions above $n$.  I think this gives the relationship to cohomological dimension that you are asking about.  Regards,

Answer (score 9):

**A implies B.** True, as you said, because a finitely generated ring is Noetherian, and $X$ is glued from finitely many spectra of such.

**A implies C.** True (argument as above).

**B implies A.** False, e.g. $X = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Q}$.

**B implies C.** False (I believe). There are rings $R$ whose spectrum is homeomorphic to the topological space $\{1, 2, \dotsc \}$ with open sets $\{n, n+1, \dotsc\}$, which is Noetherian but of infinite Krull dimension. I think something like $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1, x_1 x_2, x_1 x_2 x_3, \dotsc]$ should work, but I didn't check the details. **EDIT.** This is nonsense — see the comments below and Fred Rohrer's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/111709).

**C implies A.** False, e.g. $X= \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Q}$.

**C implies B.** False, e.g. $X = \operatorname{Spec} k[x, x^{1/2}, x^{1/3}, \dotsc]$.

Comment: Dear @Piotr, the ring $k[x_1,x_1x_2,x_1x_2x_3,...]$ is indeed of infinite dimension, but not noetherian, since its ideal generated by $x_1$, $x_1,x_2$, $x_1x_2x_3$,... is not of finite type.

Comment: Well, $x_1$, $x_1$, $x_2$ in my previous comment should obviously read $x_1$, $x_1x_2$.

Comment: Dear @Fred, isn't this ideal just generated by $x_1$, or am I missing something?

Comment: Re B implies C : By definition, a noetherian scheme $X$ is covered by finitely many spectra of noetherian rings. If $X$ has infinite Krull dimension, then one of these noetherian rings must have infinite Krull dimension. Thus we need a Nagata-like counterexample.

Comment: I think your ring $k[x_1,x_1 x_2,x_1 x_2 x_3,\ldots]$ is abstractly isomorphic to $k[X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots]$.

Comment: Dear @Piotr, if $x_1x_2$ was a multiple of $x_1$ in your ring, then (by comparison of coefficients) $x_2$ had to be an element of your ring, which it isn't. Francois' description is correct: There is an isomorphism of $k$-algebras that maps $x_1...x_i$ to $X_i$ for every $i$.

Answer (score 9):

An example of a noetherian ring of infinite dimension can be found in Nagata's *Local Rings*, Appendix A1, Example 1.

**Edit:** An interesting generalisation of Nagata's construction yielding noetherian rings of infinite dimension whose maximal ideals have prescribed heights was given by Fujita in his article [*Infinite dimensional Noetherian Hilbert domains*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/hiroshima-mathematical-journal/volume-5/issue-2/Infinite-dimensional-Noetherian-Hilbert-domains/10.32917/hmj/1206136627.full), Hiroshima Math. J. 5 (1975), 181–185.

Comment: (True, of course.)  And yet a Noetherian *local* ring must have finite Krull dimension! 