# Noetherian rings as homomorphic image of finite direct product of Noetherian domains?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian

A theorem of Hungerford says that : Every PIR (principal ideal ring , obviously commutative ) is a homomorphic image of a finite direct product of PID s . My question is , is there a similar criteria for Noetherian rings, i.e. : Is every Noetherian ring a homomorphic image of a finite direct product of Noetherian domains ?

This [Is every Noetherian Commutative Ring a quotient of a Noetherian Domain?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162030/is-every-noetherian-commutative-ring-a-quotient-of-a-noetherian-)    shows that we cannot expect every Noetherian ring to be a homomorphic image of a Noetherian domain.